# Cookies required error upon first login facebook (Atom-Electron application)

Tags: facebook, cookies, session-cookies, electron

I am building an application using Atom/Electron Library and I have a facebook login button for this application.
It is working fine. However, upon the user's first login (in Facebook's popup window), an error shows (cookie are required please enable them in your browser to log in).

I checked electron's documentation and nothing seems to be a workaround for this problems. Any help/ideas are much appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: I guess you need to enable cookies in your browser on whatever device you are testing. e.g. In an iPhone: Settings -> Safari -> Select Block Cookies -> Allow from Websites I Visit.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem

Answer (score -1):

What you need is to set webPreferences.webSecurity to false, please see snippet below:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    frame: true,
    webPreferences: {
        webSecurity: false,
        plugins: true
    }
});
```